# How to properly line-wrap a django statement to satisfy flake8?

Tags: python, flake8

This code gets `E501 line too long (85 > 79 characters)` from flake8:

```
qobjs &= Q(
    latest_visit__visitstatistics__worst_zscore__gte=worst_zscore_min_filter)
```

This code gets `E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals`:

```
qobjs &= Q(
    latest_visit__visitstatistics__worst_zscore__gte=
    worst_zscore_min_filter)
```

What is the right thing to satisfy flake8?

**EDIT**: I ended up telling flake8 to ignore with noqa.  I thought it didn't work, but I just had to [read the docs](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) more carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can't choose more sane variable names because these are machine generated, I wouldn't worry about it, and just tell `pep8` (or `pycodestyle`, or whatever `flake8` is actually using to check for PEP-8 conformance) to ignore the line:

```
qobjs &= Q(...)  # noqa
```

(Update: rather than ignore the line altogether, `# noqa: E501` would let you ignore the line length, but still check for other problems.)

If you are still using the default max line width of 79, consider using something longer. PEP-8 really only requires that width for code in the standard library, and it explicitly states that teams may agree on a longer
width.

---

The error you are getting is because the newline after `=` is counted as whitespace, as if you had typed `Q(late...gte= worse...filter)`. You could use explicit line continuation:

```
qobjs &= Q(
    latest_visit__visitstatistics__worst_zscore__gte=\
    worst_zscore_min_filter)
```

or use shorter temporary names:

```
x = 'latest_visit__visitstatistics__worst_zscore__gte'
y = worst_zscore_min_filter
qobjs &= Q(**{x: y})
```

but my preference would be to just stop trying to appease `flake8` on code that isn't supposed to be human-readable in the first place.

Comment: With regards to the first suggested option, in `flake8` the backslash after the `=` in this scenario will likely raise `E502 the backslash is redundant between brackets`, while the newline causes  `E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals` as you mentioned. Thus I would go for the option of using shorter temporary names.